# Electron: electron-builder config

Tags: javascript, linux, windows, electron

Can somebody explain to me how [electron-builder](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/wiki/Options#LinuxBuildOptions) config work? I can't understand 95% of the things. Everything bellow **API** is somehow confusing. There are **0** examples of actually how something should be added to the `build` object. I mean, look at a simple dev request: I want to create windows and linux build. I copy/paste-ed some code and I came out with the fillowing:

```
{
  "name": "Test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "author": "Test Ltd.",
  "description": "Test",
  "devDependencies": {
      ...
  },
  "build": {
    "appId": "Test",
    "extraFiles": {
      "from": "./build",
      "to": "./dist"
    },
    "win": {
      "icon" : "build/images/icon.ico",
      "target": ["portable"]
    },
    "linux": {
      "icon" : "build/images/icon.png",
      "target": ["pacman"]
    }
  },
  "scripts": {
    "pack": "build --dir",
    "dist": "build"
  }
}
```

1. It creates only x64 windows package. In the `dist` folder there is a folder called `win-unpacked` and one .exe file. The linux package is not there. Why?
2. How to specify the arch (x64, x32)?
3. How to use the things bellow **API**? I understood only how `WinBuildOptions` work - I should write "win" in the "build" object of `package.json`.
4. What is `Squirrel Events`? I red [this](https://github.com/Squirrel/Squirrel.Windows/blob/master/docs/using/custom-squirrel-events.md), but can't understand it from plain text.
5. Any recommendations for a video guide for "How to create an installer for Windows with Electron/electron-builder?" or "How to create package for Linux and upload it online so people with Linux can download it with Electron/electron-builder?" I couldn't find any.

Comment: Hi Marin, I have same problem already couple of days, I couldn't understand how to configure electron builder to make my apps' installer... If you found any good articles please link it below. Thank you : )

Comment: What most helped me was the answers bellow. I couldn't find any good articles/github of how to config the app. It's sad really. All I had in the end was windows installer. One thing I would like to mention here is that if you want you app to be updated, the user will have to uninstall the old app and install the new one. Back in 2017 I wanted the updates to be patch-like, but this was not supported. I don't know if they support this now.

Comment: Fast forward 6 years to today and the documentation still isn't helpful at all.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look a the api options in the github repo for [electron-builder](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/wiki/Options#Config), which uses the [windows](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/wiki/Options#WinBuildOptions) build options and [linux](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/wiki/Options#LinuxBuildOptions) build options to work. The descriptions of each item are laid out next to the attribute/property of the config.

This is a contrived example, but should at least give the structure of how it should look for windows and linux:

```
    "build":{
        "appid":"yourid",
        "asar": true
        "linux":{
            "category": "...",
            "target": "..."
        },
        "win":{
            "target": "...",
            "certificateFile":"...",
            "publisherName": "..."
        }

    }
```

There is a [multi platform](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/wiki/Multi-Platform-Build) build page you can review. Specifically, to target a certain arch, you use the command line flags. From the documentation:

> By default build for current platform and current arch. Use CLI flags
>   --mac, --win, --linux to specify platforms. And --ia32, --x64 to specify arch.

Typically, this is specified as an npm script, and passed along that way when you run the electon-build command. In terms of building on platforms and potentially missing information, please see this quote:

> Don't expect that you can build app for all platforms on one platform.

There appears to be extra setup and configuration needed to develop a linux and windows version based on the specific OS you are using. I would look at what that page states in terms of dependencies.

Comment: If you want to build multiple target artifacts (e.g. both a `deb` and a `7z`) for an OS, each OS's `target` actually takes an array of objects - each with its own `target`, `arch` and other keys e.g. 
`builderOptions: { linux: { category: "Education", target: [ { target: "deb", arch: [ "x64" ] }, { target: "7z", } ] }, win: { target: [ { target: "nsis", } ] } }`

Answer (score -3):

To answer part of your question you can not package an app when you are not on the platform that you want to package for example if you are on window the electron-builder will package windows app based on the machine you are using [configuration of win targets](https://www.electron.build/configuration/win)

For linux targets, see [here](https://www.electron.build/configuration/linux). The recommendation seems to be to build inside a docker container if you want to build for linux.